# AWS Lambda Node.js to write to a table after taking a JWT token using http post..Can we do both in same lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to take a jwt token using a http post and write it to a Dynomodb table. I'm trying to use it as a Lambda in AWS and invoked using the API gateway when a POST request comes it will get the token and write to the table and a GET request comes if will print it to the console. I have been trying to get the code working for a while but no luck. Can someone show me some love :-)
I'm starting to think I can't do all this with a single Lambda and need to break to 2 Lambdas. Any suggestions much appreciated!

```
//https://k3rezu1sre.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/Authorizer
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const TABLE_NAME = "MyDynoTable";
var request = require('request');

exports.handler = async(event, context) => {

 
  switch (event.requestContext.http.method) {
        
        case "GET":
            const data = await ddb.scan({ TableName: TABLE_NAME }).promise();
      
            return {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              }
            };

         case "POST":
            const { token } = JSON.parse(event.body);
            var options = {
                'method': 'POST',
                'url': 'https://host-eu.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token',
                'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
                  "audience": "urn:",
                  "client_id": "",
                  "client_secret": ""
                })
              
              };
                
              request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                 if (error) throw new Error(error);
                 const stringBodytoJason = JSON.parse(body);
                 const token = stringBodytoJason.access_token;
                 //console.log(token); 

    await ddb.put({
    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
      id: context.awsRequestId,
      token
      }
    }).promise();
    
    return {
        statusCode: 201,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: context.awsRequestId,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      };
    default:
      break; 
    } 
 
});
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: In addition Seth's question, I am curious why you are using a SCAN with this. Are you really intending to do a full table scan each time to bring back all items in the table?

Comment: Right now code execute with no errors. But it does not do anything. Not writing to the table or returning any information